# How can I scroll in the background using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a chrome extension where I have to access the `innerText` of some `span` elements. I can safely get them using simple `document.querySelector` commands.

But for some spans, it returns `null` because they don't exist yet in the DOM> (For security reasons, I cannot disclose which website this happens with but to make it more clear, [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/sachinbansal/) does a similar thing where the **Experience** block is only loaded if you scroll down to it.)

Now, to quote the problem using that example: I want to get the value of a `span` which is inside that **Experience** section. If I run the script inside `window.onload`, it returns `null` because the span isn't there yet.

One solution is to simply scroll the page, (or even worse, ask the users of the extension to first scroll the page before running the extension.) However, I do not want to do that.

Is there a way in JS to scroll the page in the background without visual feedback to the user so that I can get the value of the HTML elements that are initially hidden?

Assume that the span I want to get has the following class: `defense-rc4`

Comment: You can do that on frameworks like vuejs or react using lifecycle hooks in react you can execute a method, function before the initial rendering of component using componentWillMount().

Comment: True. But Since I am not the owner of the website my extension will run on, that method cannot work.

Comment: @barbsan Please read the question and question title again.

Comment: Perhaps you could give the container a `visibility:hidden`, move it into the viewport and use a `MutationObserver` to determine when the span loads. Once you've accessed the span you move the container back and restore its visibility.